# При команде git pull выводит ошибку

Tags: git, git-pull, git-remote

Когда ввожу команду `git pull`

```
 There is no tracking information for the current branch.
    Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
    See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master
```

и еще в команде `git log` не выводит все коммиты, которые  изменял в проекте, будто он не видит связь удаленным репо!

Answer (score 1):

Пора все-таки выучить английский, без него в программировании никуда.

От вас требуют указать удаленную ветку при пулле, которая будет смержена в локальную

git pull remote_branch

Comment: а что  в `remote` тогда указывается

Comment: название удаленной ветки

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

`git branch -l`  Получите название текущей ветки - она отмечена '*'

`git pull origin NAME_OF_BRANCH` - NAME_OF_BRANCH - название тек. ветки

Comment: Jigius,  `git pull origin NAME_OF_BRANCH` нет связи с удаленным репо! 

 при команде `git pull  git@bitbucket____some.git`


`From git@bitbucket____some.git
 * branch              HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: какой вывод был у первой команды - `git branch -l`?

Comment: обычно адрес удаленного проверяется  репо
`git remote -v` но ничего не выводит

`git branch -l` указывает на бранч `master`

git pull origin master

`fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Значит у вас нет удаленной ветки. Либо она по  какой-то причине была ранее убрана или этот репозиторий никогда не клонировался.